# An uncountable structure with unusual "relatively-computable shadow"

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, forcing

*Below, all structures are infinite and in a finite language. Given a structure $\mathcal{A}$ with domain $\omega$, we conflate $\mathcal{A}$ with some reasonable encoding of its atomic diagram for computational purposes.*

Given **countable** structures $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ in possibly-different languages, write $\mathcal{A}\le_w\mathcal{B}$ ("$\mathcal{A}$ is weakly/Muchnik reducible to $\mathcal{B}$") iff every isomorphic copy of $\mathcal{B}$ with domain $\omega$ computes some isomorphic copy of $\mathcal{A}$ with domain $\omega$. This is a $\Pi^1_2$ property, so basic facts about it behave reasonably well with respect to forcing. In particular, for **possibly-uncountable** structures $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$, write $\mathcal{A}\le_w^*\mathcal{B}$ iff $\Vdash_{Col(\omega,\mathcal{A}\sqcup\mathcal{B})}\mathcal{A}\le_w\mathcal{B}$; then $\mathcal{A}\le_w^*\mathcal{B}$ is equivalent to "$\mathcal{A}\le_w\mathcal{B}$ in *every* generic extension in which each is countable," and $\le_w^*$ agrees with $\le_w$ on countable structures.

There are plenty of examples of uncountable structures $\ge_w^*$ uncountably many countable structures; for instance, construing ordinals as linear orders as usual, it's a fun exercise to show the countable structures $\le_w^*\omega_1$ are precisely the countable structures $\le_w$ some countable ordinal. There are also examples of uncountable structures $\equiv_w^*$ some countable structure (e.g. any uncountable dense linear order without endpoints is $\equiv_w^*\mathbb{Q}$, since they are potentially isomorphic).

I'm curious whether an extreme alternative to this is possible. Given a structure (of arbitrary cardinality) $\mathcal{X}$, let $M_0(\mathcal{X})$ be the class of *countable* structures $\le_w^*\mathcal{X}$. My question, then, is:

> Suppose $\mathcal{X}$ is an uncountable structure such that $M_0(\mathcal{X})$ is countable. Must $M_0(\mathcal{X})$ have a $\le_w$-greatest element?

Shoenfield absoluteness is a natural thing to reach for, but I don't see how it applies here.

Comment: Do you know if there's any countable collection of countable structures without a least upper bound in the $\leq_w$ ordering?

Comment: @PatrickLutz I vaguely recall being told that there are, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @PatrickLutz I'm fairly confident that the collection of hyperarithemetically presentable structures has no least upper bound.

Comment: If $M_0(\mathcal{X})$ is countable, then in particular there are only countably many $\Delta_1$-definable substructures of $\mathcal{X}$.  I feel like there should be some sort of countable limit object, which would then be *-isomorphic to $\mathcal{X}$ (and thus the largest element of $M_0(\mathcal{X})$).

Comment: @DanTuretsky That's plausible, but too vague for me to tease into a detailed argument at the moment.